# Is the de Sitter Universe equivalent to the static Einstein Universe?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, de-sitter-spacetime

The [de Sitter universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe) is a flat exponentially expanding universe with a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ and no matter.

[Einstein's static universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_universe) also has a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ but it also has matter and it is static. Can we make some coordinate transformation to the de Sitter universe to show equivalence of the universes?

Comment: No, they aren't equivalent. For a start the de Sitter universe is open while the Einstein static universe can be open or closed.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not interpreting the Einstein-de Sitter universe as equivalence of the de Sitter universe and Einstein universe?

Comment: @Immanuel Yes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The de Sitter universe is a [...] universe with [...] no matter.
>
> Einstein's static universe [...] has matter
>
> Can we make some coordinate transformation to the de Sitter universe to show equivalence of the universes?

Coordinate transformations cannot change the zero energy-momentum tensor of a de Sitter universe into the non-zero energy-momentum tensor of an Einstein uiverse.